# CSS - My UL is Stuck in the Header

Tags: html, css

The site I'm trying to build is a copy of an old BBC layout. I'm trying to make the "News" tab move over towards the left, but it won't move. I don't know what the problem is. I've tried changing margins and padding. That doesn't seem to work. I've also tried changing the position to relative in some parts and doing left:-50. The text just won't move.

The images and the "Sign In" text in the code snippet won't load because they're on my computer. So just ignore the empty space to the left.

```css
     <style type="text/css">
  
  body{
   margin:0;
  }
  #topbar{
   background-color:#700001;
   width:100%;
   height:44px;
   color:white;
   font-weight:bold;
   font-family:Ariel, Helvetica, sans serif;
   font-size:1em;
  }
  
  .fixedwidth{
   width:1050px;
   margin:0 auto;
  }
  
  #logodiv{
   padding:3px 8px 0px 0px;
   position:relative;
   left:-150px;
   float:left;
   border-right:1px #9F0003 solid;
  }
  
  #signindiv{
   position:relative;
   left:-145px;
   float:left;
   padding:2px 80px 13px 5px;
   border-right:1px #9F0003 solid;
  }
  
  #signindiv img{
   position:relative;
   top:5px;
  }
  
  #topmenudiv{
   float:left;
  }
  
  #topmenudiv ul{
   margin:13px 5px 13px 5px;
   float:left;
  }
  
  #topmenudiv li{
   list-style:none;
  }
  
    </style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fake BBC</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
     
</head>

<body>
 
 <div id="container">
 
  <div id="topbar">
  
  <div class="fixedwidth">
   
  <div id="logodiv">
   <img src="images/bbclogo.png" />
  </div>
  
  <div id="signindiv">
   <img src="images/signinlogo.png" /> Sign In
  </div>
   
  </div> 
  
  <div id="topmenudiv">
  
   <ul>
   
    <li>News</li>
   
   </ul>
  
  </div>
 
 </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, here is https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/7/

Update your css with this

```
    body{
        margin:0;
    }

    #topbar{
        background-color:#700001;
        width:100%;
        height:44px;
        color:white;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-family:Ariel, Helvetica, sans serif;
        font-size:1em;
    }

    .fixedwidth{
        width:1050px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    #logodiv{
        padding:3px 8px 0px 0px;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        border-right:1px #9F0003 solid;
    }

    #signindiv{
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        padding:8px 10px;
        border-right:1px #9F0003 solid;
    }

    #signindiv img{
        position:relative;
    }

    #topmenudiv{
        float:left;
    }

    #topmenudiv ul{
        margin:8px 10px;
        float:left;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    #topmenudiv li{
        list-style:none;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, What about no?
This issue is not on his CSS, 
Issue is that he lost a Closing Div, code working without messing up with the css.

Comment: Yea i also fixed that closing div in my `HTML`, and YES the problem is in css.

Answer (score 1):

That's Because you missed a closing

```
 </div>
```

Your Indentation is awful.

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="topbar">
            <div class="fixedwidth">
                <div id="logodiv">
                    <img src="images/bbclogo.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="signindiv">
                    <img src="images/signinlogo.png" /> Sign In
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="topmenudiv">
                <ul>
                    <li>News</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Or

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="topbar">
            <div class="fixedwidth">
                <div id="logodiv">
                    <img src="images/bbclogo.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="signindiv">
                    <img src="images/signinlogo.png" /> Sign In
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="topmenudiv">
            <ul>
                <li>News</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm not sure where you missed it. Even though i'm pretty sure its the first one.